# ESP8266 stuck in flash mode?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, flash

I have the setup described here: https://learn.adafruit.com/esp8266-temperature-slash-humidity-webserver/wiring

I currently have the reset pin set to float and the GPIO0 pin grounded, which should make it execute the uploaded program, but instead I get the flash mode output:

```
    writing flash
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

How do I put it into execution mode?

Comment: Try putting a pullup on Reset and GPIO0.

Comment: `GPIO0 pin grounded, which should make it execute` - no, GPIO0 grounded is how to put the thing into programming mode

Comment: What is the correct configuration then?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a similar scenario. I managed to exit programming mode by floating GIPO0, then grounding RST for ~3 seconds, then floating it. If you power off the esp, and now turn it on, it should have exited programming mode. Powering it off is actually optional.